# Comparing worksheet Name in workbook to get total no of matched sheets

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I have this following code that counts the total no of specific worksheets in a workbook. I used the vbTextCompare operator (comparison operator) to match the Name of worksheet, if it's there then it would count the no of sheets. But unfortunately, this is not matching the string. any help? 
the worksheets names are in the following order BQ1, BQ2,BQ3..... and so on..

```
Dim tSheets As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

 i = 1
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If StrComp(Left(WS.Name, 1), "BQ" & i, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        tSheets = tSheets + 1
        MsgBox WS.Name
            i = i + 1
    End If

Next WS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I refactored your code using `Left`, `Right`, and `Len`.

```
Sub CountBQSheets()
    Const WSPrefix As String = "BQ"
    Dim tSheets As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(UCase(ws.Name), Len(WSPrefix)) = WSPrefix Then
            If IsNumeric(Right(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - Len(WSPrefix))) Then
                tSheets = tSheets + 1
                MsgBox ws.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I think using a collection to collect the names would be more useful.

```
Sub Test_getWSPrefixList()
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = getWSPrefixList(ThisWorkbook, "BQ")

    Debug.Print Join(list.ToArray, ",")

End Sub

Function getWSPrefixList(wb As Workbook, WSPrefix As String) As Object
    Dim list As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(UCase(ws.Name), Len(WSPrefix)) = WSPrefix Then
            If IsNumeric(Right(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - Len(WSPrefix))) Then
                list.Add ws.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    Set getWSPrefixList = list
End Function
```

---

```
BQ20,BQ19,BQ18,BQ17,BQ16,BQ15,BQ14,BQ13,BQ12,BQ11,BQ10,BQ9,BQ8,BQ7,BQ6,BQ5,BQ4,BQ3,BQ2,BQ1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code...

1. You are comparing the first letter of sheet name with the string variable "BQ" & i. So it will not match in any case.
2. The second issue is, you are incrementing the i at the wrong place. It should be outside the IF block.

Try something like this...

```
Dim tSheets As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If StrComp(WS.Name, "BQ" & i, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        tSheets = tSheets + 1
        MsgBox WS.Name
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next WS
```

Comment: Intentionally putting i inside if block. so that it should only increment i after the matched string is found. Btw, I've found the solution..  I was comparing 1 letter of the sheet name instead of 1 there should be 3

Comment: @Hola In that case you should use to counter variable, one to use with dynamically construct the sheet name and another to count the occurrences of found sheets, where as you used only one counter variable. Yes, that's what I pointed out that you were comparing only the first letter of sheet names. If your question is resolved, please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.